# Riverpod 2.3.6 AutoDisposeNotifier and ref.onDispose

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using Riverpod version 2.3.6 and have some problems with `ref.onDispose` for `AutoDisposeNotifier`.

1. I have created an `AutoDisposeNotifierProvider` and a `ref.onDispose` function inside build of `AutoDisposeNotifier`.
   Pressing the "Set Text TextField" button will set text to Text and TextField but when "Goto Screen2" the `ref.onDispose` function is not triggered unless I am calling `ref.invalidate(newStringLabel)` at "Goto Screen2". Isn't `AutoDisposeNotifier` supposed to automatically trigger the `ref.onDispose` function?
2. I am using `TextEditingController` and trying to Dispose it inside the `ref.onDispose` function but receiving the error "A ${notifier.runtimeType} was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a ${notifier.runtimeType}, it can no longer be used." So how can I Dispose `TextEditingController`?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

final textController = TextEditingController();

final newStringLabel =
    AutoDisposeNotifierProvider<NewStringLabel, String>(NewStringLabel.new);

class NewStringLabel extends AutoDisposeNotifier<String> {
  @override
  String build() {
    ref.onDispose(() {
      print('Dispose triggered.');
      //textController.dispose();
      textController.clear();
    });
    return "Init text";
  }

  void toCamelCase() {
    state = 'some text from provider';
    print(state);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Home',
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    textController.text = 'Set some text to TextField';
                    ref.read(newStringLabel.notifier).toCamelCase();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Set Text TextField')),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(ref.watch(newStringLabel)),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
              child: TextField(
                controller: textController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Goto Screen2'),
              onPressed: () {
                //ref.invalidate(newStringLabel);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen2()),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Screen2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

№1. The point is that you are still using the provider in the widget tree. To verify this, try moving to a new page like this:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen2()),
);
```

As for problem №2, I would suggest using `ConsumerStatefulWidget` and using the `dispose` and `initState` methods to properly use and dispose of your `textController`. Moreover, make it a field of this widget (possible with `late`).